# assign specific characters to rows in a data frame

Tags: r

I have huge data frame that looks like this in R

```
    scan_id       sample
1  s8w_00001.sed      1
2  s8w_00001.sed      1
3  s9w_00001.sed      1
4 s10w_00001.sed      1
5 s11d_00002.sed      1
6 s12w_00004.sed      1
7 s13w_00001.sed      1
8 s14w_00001.sed      1
```

The column labelled sample should have values that correspond with the column labelled scan_id. So for an observation where I have scan_id= s8w_00001.sed, sample should be 8. Because there is an 8 in that line of characters. I should have something that looks like this.

```
 scan_id          sample
1  s8w_00001.sed      8
2  s8w_00002.sed      8
3  s9w_00001.sed      9
4 s10w_00001.sed     10
5 s11d_00002.sed     11
6 s12w_00004.sed     12
7 s13w_00001.sed     13
8 s14w_00001.sed     14
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub`, i.e

```
gsub('s([0-9]+)[a-z]+_.*$', '\\1', df$scan_id)
#[1] "8"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract the first digit(s) from your `scan_id` column, you can use `mutate(data, sample = str_extract(scan_id, "[:digit:]+"))` from the `tidyverse`. In this case the first set of digits is extracted.

If you want to specifiy the pattern before your digits, use `mutate(data, sample = str_extract(scan_id, "(?<=[:alpha:]+)[:digit:]+"))`. In this case the first set of digits that is preceded by a set of letters is extracted.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the `stri_extract_first_regex` from `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)
# Extract the one occurance of a digit [0-9]+ ('+' matches 1 or more digits)
df$samples <- stri_extract_first_regex(df$scan_id, "[0-9]+")
```

And the output

```
> df
         scan_id sample samples
1  s8w_00001.sed      1       8
2  s8w_00001.sed      1       8
3  s9w_00001.sed      1       9
4 s10w_00001.sed      1      10
5 s11d_00002.sed      1      11
6 s12w_00004.sed      1      12
7 s13w_00001.sed      1      13
8 s14w_00001.sed      1      14
```

Where `df` is:

```
df <- read.table(text = "scan_id       sample
  s8w_00001.sed      1
  s8w_00001.sed      1
  s9w_00001.sed      1
 s10w_00001.sed      1
 s11d_00002.sed      1
 s12w_00004.sed      1
 s13w_00001.sed      1
 s14w_00001.sed      1", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Also same result with `stringr::str_extract(df$scan_id, "\\d+")`

Comment: True, and the same goes for `sub("\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$scan_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
df$sample <- gsub("\\D", "", sapply(strsplit(df$scan_id, "_"), function(x) x[1]))

         scan_id sample
1  s8w_00001.sed      8
2  s8w_00001.sed      8
3  s9w_00001.sed      9
4 s10w_00001.sed     10
5 s11d_00002.sed     11
6 s12w_00004.sed     12
7 s13w_00001.sed     13
8 s14w_00001.sed     14
```

Here it splits the "scan_id" on `_` and then extracts the numbers from the first element after split.

Comment: `chartr` and `dirname` might also be useful here: `gsub("[^0-9]+", "", dirname(chartr("_", "/", dat$scan_id)))` So you can avoid `sapply`

Comment: @markus an interesting possibility, really. I need to examine it in detail.